# json.Decoder does not work for larger messages sent over unixpacket

Tags: go

Consider the code shown below. A Unix domain socket connection is established of type `unixpacket`. A JSON message is sent into the connection on one end and read on the other using Go's [json.Decoder](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder). This works as expected up to the number of `{"foo":123}` objects shown. But, if I add one more `{"foo":123}` object to the array in the message, then json.Decoder no longer works (it just hangs and never returns). Why is that?

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    addr := "/tmp/uds_test.sock"
    network := "unixpacket"

    l, err := net.Listen(network, addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer l.Close()

    quit := make(chan bool)
    defer func() { quit <- true }()
    
    go func() {
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        defer conn.Close()
        _, err = conn.Write([]byte(msg))
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
            return
        }
        <-quit
    }()

    conn, err := net.Dial(network, addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    m := &json.RawMessage{}
    if err := json.NewDecoder(conn).Decode(m); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(*m))
}

const msg = `[
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123},
    {"foo":123}
]
`
```

Question Part 2:

If I replace `json.NewDecoder(conn).Decode(m)` with the following function, then I can add more objects to the message array without any issues:

```golang
func readJSON(r io.Reader, v interface{}) error {
    bytes := make([]byte, 65536)
    length, err := r.Read(bytes)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return json.Unmarshal(bytes[:length], v)
}
```

What I don't like about this solution is that I now need to set the size of the bytes array that the message is being read into. I liked the json.Decoder approach for its dynamic behaviour. I also tried using [io.ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#ReadAll), but that doesn't work presumably because `unixpacket` messages are not delimited by EOF. Given that [unixpacket preserves message boundaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket), is there a message delimiter that can be read up to in Go?

Comment: unix packets (SOCK_DGRAM), like UDP, are individual datagrams. There is no stream to decode, so you would need to re-assemble the payload yourself, and decide yourself what the delimiter is.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking then “unixpacket” corresponds to SOCK_SEQPACKET, not SOCK_DGRAM.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot that it's `SOCK_SEQPACKET` (as opposed to `unixgram`) and should have put that `SOCK_DGRAM` note against UDP. It's still a packet connection however, and has the same message semantics as `SOCK_DGRAM` except it's ordered and connection-based. This means it's intended for individual packets up to a specific size, not a stream, and if you want to stream data over it you need to re-assemble that stream.

Comment: Packet connections (which are almost always `SOCK_DGRAM`) send and receive individual, _complete_ packets. You only get one call to read the packet, so if you send a huge packet and the receiver isn't explicitly expecting it and only reads part of it, the rest is discarded. See the socket man page with SOCK_SEQPACKET here:  https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html

Comment: Thanks JimB, this is very helpful! Does that mean there's no way of reading a packet without using a fixed size bytes array? In other words, can a packet be read into a slice instead of an array (see part 2 of my question)?

Comment: I don't understand, you always read into a slice, but you must always know how large a packet you intend to accept. This isn't really related to Go, this is how packet connections work at the OS level.

Comment: Ok, sounds like I need to do some reading on the fundamentals of packet connections. Many thanks for your help!